# Find a matrix $A \in M_{2,2}\mathbb{R}$ and a vector $ v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with the two properties

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a matrix $A \in M_{2,2}\mathbb{R}$ and a vector $ v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with the two properties:

1. $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$
2. for all of the eigenvectors of $A$ it applies that $v' \in \langle v \rangle$

$\langle v \rangle = v_{1} ... v_{n}$

Is the $A$ diagonalisable? I'm still struggling how to start to solve the problem, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Is $v'$ an eigenvector? And what do you mean with $< v > = v_1 \dots v_n$?

Comment: What necessary/sufficient conditions do you know about diagonalisability? Particularly, do you know any regarding bases of eigenvectors or dimensions of eigenspaces?

Comment: yes, $v'$ is an eigenvector and $< v > = v_1 \dots v_n$ this is the set of all vectors in $v$

Comment: Set of all vectors in a vector ? Does that make sense ? Did you mean in the space generated by $v$ ?

Comment: I'm also struggling by understanding of this example this is the description from my professor to the problem.

Comment: "this is the description from my professor to the problem." perhaps, but it seems much more likely that this is your garbled version of the professor's description. (I can't believe that a professor said $<v>=v_1,\dots v_n$ is "the set of vectors in $v$". If you tell us _exactly_ what was said we could tell you what that meant...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the notation $\langle v \rangle$ . It is the subspace generated by $v$ and defined by

$\langle v \rangle =\{\alpha v: \alpha \in \mathbb{F}\}$   where $\mathbb{F}$ is the underlying Field.

Take the matrix

$$
    A=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$

Then the characterisrics polynomial is $p(x)=x^2$  and so the only eigen value is zero.

Now , since the rank of $A$ is $1$, $dim(KerA)=2-1=1$ where $KerA$ is actually the eigen space corresponding to zero eigen value.

So there is at least one $v(\ne 0)$ such that $Av=0v=0$

Try to find such $v$ by taking $v=(x_1,x_2)^T$ and solving $Av=0$ for $x_1,x_2$

You will find $x_1$ is arbitary and $x_2=0$ . So easily I can take $v=(1,0)$  for $x_1=1$

Now if there is eigen vector $v'$ then it must be eigen vector corresponding to eigen value $0$ since there are no other eigen values.

Now if  $v'=(x_1' ,x_2')$ then again we must have $x_2'=0$ .

Thus $v'=x_1'v\in \langle v \rangle  $

Note that I am using $0$ in the RHS of $Av=0$ to denote $(0,0)^T$

Hope this is helpful.